# canvas API simulation of analog clock

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, canvas

I have tried to create a simulation of the analog clock in Canvas API. I do not want to use a time object because my clock is not going to tell the actual time. The clock should have three hands (for seconds, minutes, and hours). When a document is loaded hands should point to 9.00 and then hands will start moving.
I have drawn a clock body and hands. The hand that shows second goes around as I want. However, I do not know how to move hands that show minutes and hours. I have tried to use the variable 'counter' for counting the loops and whenever the counter is divisible by 60 move the hand that shows the minute for a 6-degree angle. The same logic I wanted to apply for the hand that shows the hours (when the counter is divisible by 3600 to move the hand for a 30-degree angle). Could somebody give me a hand or hint how I can achieve it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Analog Clock</title>
    <style>
        #my-canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="my-canvas" width="400" height="300">
        Your web browser does not support canvas.
    </canvas>
    <script>
        window.onload = draw;
                function draw() {
                    let myCanvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');

                    if(myCanvas.getContext) {
                        let ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
                        // set interval to one second
                        setInterval(function() {
                            update(ctx);
                        }, 1000);
                    } else {
                        alert('Canvas is not supported.')
                    }
                }
                // set the counter
                let ct = 0;
                
                // set angles for clock hands
                let angleS = 6;
                let angleM = 6;
                let angleH = 30;

                // update function
                function update(ctx) {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
                    ctx.save();

                    showClock(ctx);
                    showHands(ctx);
                    
                    ctx.restore()
                }
                
                // show the clock 
                function showClock(ctx) {

                    // draw circle - body of the clock 
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(120, 120, 120, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                    ctx.stroke();
                    
                    // show clock "brand"
                    ctx.font = "18px Arial";
                    ctx.fillText('Timex', 98, 75);
                    
                    // show numbers 12, 3, 6 i 9
                    ctx.font = "43px serif";
                    ctx.fillText("12", 100, 40);
                    ctx.fillText("3", 215, 135);
                    ctx.fillText("6", 110, 235);
                    ctx.fillText("9", 5, 135);

                    // draw the center of the clock
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(120,120, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.stroke();
                    
                }

                // show hands
                function showHands(ctx) {
                    ct += 1;
                    console.log(ct);

                    // draw hand for seconds
                    ctx.translate(120, 120);
                    ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180) * angleS);
                    ctx.translate(-120, -120); 

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(120, 120);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
                    ctx.lineTo(120, 10);
                    ctx.stroke();

                    // increase angle for 6 degrees 
                    angleS +=6;

                    if (ct < 60) {
                        // draw hands for minutes
                        ctx.restore();
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(120, 120);
                        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
                        ctx.lineTo(120, 30);
                        ctx.stroke();
                    }

                    if (ct%60==0) {
                        
                        ctx.translate(120, 120);
                        ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180) * angleM);
                        ctx.translate(-120, -120); 
                        ctx.restore();

                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(120, 120);
                        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
                        ctx.lineTo(120, 30);
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.restore();
                        // increase angle for minutes
                        angleM +=6;

                    } 
                        
                    
                    
                    

                        
                        

                    

                
                    // draw hands for hours
                    ctx.restore();
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(120, 120);
                    
                    ctx.lineWidth = 9;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
                    ctx.lineTo(45,120);
                    ctx.stroke();   
                }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (ct < 60)` this part won't work for 61, 62, etc.  That whole block could be in the else clause of `if (ct%60==0)`.

Comment: I agree with Yogi that `setInterval()` is problematic. First I tried with `requestAnimatioinFrame` but I could not set the speed of the hands. In addition, pay attention that my clock doesn't show the actual time. It actually should work as a stopwatch starting at 9.00 but without a stop button.

Comment: I have tried if (ct%60==0) and the rest of the cases in the else block but the hand will be visible at the right position only in the case when the if statement is true. After that hand will be visible on the starting position. I need to change my code so that after hand for minutes (or hours) moves for a certain angle it will be visible in the new position until the next change. And the previous position of the hand has to clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially two problems:

1. The Canvas API methods: `save()` and `restore()` are not being used correctly.
2. I should have followed  Single Responsibility principle. The If statement is necessary for changing the angle of the hands, however it is not needed for drawing the hands.

Finally, I do not need condition `if (ct  % 3600==0)` due to the fact that hand that shows the hours  moves gradually every minute for 0.5 degrees (not 30 degrees at once when 60 minutes pass).

Now, the analog clock works as it should.  It starts from 09.00 and continues as long as the script is open in the browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Analog Clock - simulation</title>
  <style>
    #my-canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id='my-canvas' width='400' height='300'>
    Your web browser does not support canvas.
  </canvas>
  <script>
    // set the counter variable
    let ct = 0;
    
    // set the angles of the clock hands
    let angleS = 0;
    let angleM = 0;
    let angleH = 0;
    
    window.onload = draw;
    
    function draw() {
      let myCanvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
      
      if (myCanvas.getContext) {
        let ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
        
        showClock(ctx);
        showHands(ctx);
        
         // set interval to one second
         setInterval(function() { 
           update(ctx); 
         }, 1000);
       } else {
          alert('Canvas is not supported');
       }
    }
    
    // update function: clock mechanics and drawing
    function update(ctx) {
      // increase anlge for 6 degrees and counter for 1
      angleS += 6;
      ct += 1;
      
      if (ct % 60 == 0) {
        angleM += 6;
        angleH += 0.5;
      }
      
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
      showClock(ctx);
      showHands(ctx);
    }
    
    // draw hand for hours
    function drawHourHand(ctx) {
      ctx.save();
      
      ctx.translate(120, 120);
      ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180)* angleH);
      ctx.translate(-120, -120);
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(120, 120);
      ctx.lineWidth = 9;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.lineTo(45, 120);
      ctx.stroke();
      
      ctx.restore();
    }
    
    //draw hand for minutes
    function drawMinuteHand(ctx) {
      ctx.save();
      
      ctx.translate(120, 120);
      ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180)* angleM);
      ctx.translate(-120, -120);
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(120, 120);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.lineTo(120, 30);
      ctx.stroke();
      
      ctx.restore();
    }
    
    // draw hand for seconds
    function drawSecondHand(ctx) {
      ctx.save();
      
      ctx.translate(120, 120);
      ctx.rotate((Math.PI/180)* angleS);
      ctx.translate(-120, -120);
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(120, 120);
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
      ctx.lineTo(120, 10);
      ctx.stroke();
      
      ctx.restore();
    }
    
    // draw the clock body
    function showClock(ctx) {
      ctx.save();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(120, 120, 120, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.stroke();
      
      ctx.font = '18px Arial';
      ctx.fillText('Timex', 98, 75);
      
      ctx.font = '43px serif';
      ctx.fillText('12', 100, 40);
      ctx.fillText('3', 215, 135);
      ctx.fillText('6', 110, 235);
      ctx.fillText('9', 5, 135);
      
      // drae the center of the clock
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(120, 120, 10, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      
      ctx.restore();
    }
    
    // show hands
    function showHands(ctx) {
      drawHourHand(ctx);
      drawMinuteHand(ctx);
      drawSecondHand(ctx);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```